# Hadoop open source design and implementation

Tags: sentiment-analysis, big-data

I have a big project to analyse the client’s history, records in order to predict and manage the resources more efficiently. This has to deal with millions of data sets flew from various resources. My question here, what is the best tool / predictive technique allow me to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated!